# How to remove the Big Fonted Chapter X before the title of the chapter?

Tags: chapters

[image]
Hello everyone. I want to remove the Big and Bolded "Chapter 1" from the start of the chapter. Each chapter has this Chapter X title but I do not like this.
This is the code of that chapter. \

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Diagrams}
\begin{figure}[h]% The [h] means that the image should be here.
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2,center]{Images/Moonlight.jpg}
    \caption{Testing the LaTex.}
    \label{fig: This is a test.}
\end{figure}
This is a grammar test. Hi, how are you?
```

Here is my `main.tex` code.

```
\documentclass[Times,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=170mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}%To manage images and diagrams.
\usepackage{caption} % To use caption with figure and images
\usepackage{array} % The array environment is used to make a table of information, with column alignment (left, center, or right) and optional vertical lines separating the columns
\usepackage{ulem}%For properly underlining the text. Default underlining systems could cause problems.
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% Enables us to write center, right or left in "includegraphics" to position image.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% To use many kinds of page styles.
\usepackage{hyperref}% Provides LaTeX the ability to create hyperlinks within the document.
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=black,
    citecolor=blue,
}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}%To add bibliography on the content menu and create better list of contents.


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % removes page number from title page
\input{Parts_of_the_report/Tittle_and_Abstract} % Add title page
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\clearpage%Clearing the page style beacuse, we are introducing the new page numbering style.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}%For removing the annoying header line.
\lfoot{Page \thepage}%Position of the page number.

\include{Parts_of_the_report/Ch_1.tex}

\include{Parts_of_the_report/Ch_2.tex}

\include{Parts_of_the_report/Ch_3.tex}

\include{Parts_of_the_report/Ch_4.tex}

\include{Parts_of_the_report/Ch_5.tex}

\include{Parts_of_the_report/Ch_6.tex}

\include{Parts_of_the_report/Ch_7.tex}

\appendix
\include{Parts_of_the_report/Appendix}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try to code `\chapter{Introduction}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add before `\usepackage{hyperref}`

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
```

[image: a]

The package `titlesec` provides the command `\titleformat` to customize the section titles, (of `\chapter` in this case).

```
\titleformat{⟨section command⟩}{<format>}{<label before>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!